# Form stops automatically submitting after second text box is added?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

Okay so I am having an issue where if I add a second text box to my form it will not automatically submit any reason as to why?

```
<div id="myModal_play" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close icon-remove" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Start Game</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure you want to put the game <span id="modal-game-play-name"></span> (Serial Num: <span id="modal-game-play-serial"></span>) into play?</p>
        <p>Please scan the box to put the game into play</p>
        {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'game.verifygame_post', 'class'=> 'form-horizontal')) }}
        <div class="control-group ">
            {{ Form::label('cash', 'Starting Cash Amount:', array('class' => 'control-label')) }}
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-append">{{ Form::text('cash', null, array('autofocus' => 'autofocus', 'placeholder' => 'Amount in till')) }}</div>
            </div>
            <br>
            {{ Form::label('barcode', 'Click and scan barcode', array('class' => 'control-label')) }}
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-append">{{ Form::text('barcode', null, array('autofocus' => 'autofocus')) }}</div>
                <div class="input-append"><input id="hidden_serial" name="hidden_serial" type="hidden"/></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{ Form::close() }}
        <p>This action cannot be undone.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above looks like so:

[image]

javascript:

```
function put_into_play(game_name, serial) {
   $('#modal-game-play-name').html(game_name);
   $('#modal-game-play-serial').html(serial);
    document.getElementById('hidden_serial').value = serial;
}
```

If I remove the first text box "Starting Cash Amount:" and scan the text box it will work fine.

But if I add that first textbox to this it will not submit after the scan happens?
Any ideas on how I could fix this?

Comment: can you create a js fiddle for your problem

Comment: not sure that is possible since I am using laravel framework and I would need to convert all current laravel stuff to regular HTML which I dont got time for right now :/

Comment: It's a bit complicated without seeing the generated code. Do you have a link or something?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I believe this is the way to go about it.
I added a keyup call like so:

```
   $('#modal-game-play-name').html(game_name);
   $('#modal-game-play-serial').html(serial);
    document.getElementById('hidden_serial').value = serial;
    $('#barcode').keyup(function(){
        if (this.value.length == 20){
            $('#verify_game_form').submit();
        }
    });
```

This will than wait for 20 characters to be entered once they have it will automatically submit the form.